# LDAP ds 389 bind url for ldapadd

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have installed DS 389 LDAP on my centos 6.2 Linux. I was able to connect to ds console using admin and password. 
try to add the record using ldapadd command, but getting authentication failure.

```
ldapadd -f u.ldif -D "cn=Directory Administrators,dc=example,dc=net" -w password
```

How do I configure this bind CN password?

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in faq: for ds-389 I need use cn=direcory manager

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=directory manager" -w newpassword -s base -b "" "objectclass=*"
```

[http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto:ResetDirMgrPassword](http://directory.fedoraproject.org/wiki/Howto%3aResetDirMgrPassword)